# How to get “Subl” to work in my terminal?

Tags: terminal, iterm, ruby

Whenever I enter "subl" in the command line of iTerm it tells me that the command is not found. I have seen many message boards pertaining to this and nothing seems to work.

I have tried entering "ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/.rvm/bin/subl" but iTerm tells me there is no such file or directory.

This post (https://gist.github.com/artero/1236170) is also a popular solution but when I enter "open ~/.bash_profile" in my command line, it opens the generic text editor and "export PATH=" is NOT found at the top.. there really isn't much in there

I've read about bin files and home directories and this and that and now I'm just feeling a bit lost and don't know why this seemingly small issue has turned into such a problem. Just trying to do simple things like "subl ." and have my whole directory open in Sublime Text 2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand why you want to store it in the `~/.rvm/bin/` as that is supposed to be used for ruby related things and Sublime Text is not really that.

Instead place it in `/usr/local/bin` with `sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text \2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl`

If you get that error using this, try to type it in instead. There could be hidden characters that messing things up for you.

Comment: I actually have problems myself when trying to copy the content from the text here into the terminal. Write it out instead.

Comment: Got it Hoshts.. Was having an issue using my sudo command (password related) but got that sorted out so now I'm on my way. Thanks for taking the time to answer this.

Comment: You are most welcome.